# Questions about Zeta Function of Singular Plane Curve

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I am working on a project which involves learning about the zeta function (weil zeta function) for plane curves, but I do not know much algebraic geometry. (I do not know anything about schemes).

I am mostly interested in irreducible projective plane curves $C$ over finite fields $\mathbb{F}_q$. We define the zeta function by

$$Z(C, t) = \exp\left(\sum^{\infty}_{n = 1}{\frac{\# C(\mathbb{F}_{q^n})}{n} t^n}\right)$$

My supervisor has told me some facts about the zeta function for plane curves, and I am seeking a reference for these facts. I would also like to  know under what conditions these facts hold true, in particular whether they are still true even when the curve is *singular*, or if they are still true if the curve is an affine plane curve.

The facts I want information about are:

1. For a plane curve $C \subseteq \mathbb{A}^2$ given by $f(x,y) = 0$ with $f \in \mathbb{F}_q[x,y]$, the zeta function $Z(C,t)$ is rational. Also, for a plane curve $C \subseteq \mathbb{P}^2$, $Z(C,t)$ is rational.
2. $Z(C,t) = \frac{f(t)}{(1-t)(1-qt)}$, i.e. the denominator has the form $g(t) = (1-t)(1-qt)$. My understanding is that this the case for irreducible projective plane curves, whether or not the curve is singular or non-singular. Is this also true for affine plane curves?
3. When the (irreducible projective plane) curve is *non-singular*, we have $f(t) = 1 + a_1 t + \dots + a_g t^g + q a_{g-1} t^{g+1} + \dots + q^g t^{2g}$. My understanding is that this is not the case when the curve is *singular*.

Comment: Have you tried computing some examples? Try computing, for instance, the 
zeta function of the nodal cubic $C = y^2 = x^2(x - 1)$ in $\mathbf{A}^2$, and of its closure $\overline{C}$ in $\mathbf{P}^2$. Since $C$ is "almost" isomorphic to $\mathbf{P}^1$, it is not hard to count its points and write down $Z(C, T)$ and $Z(\overline{C}, T)$ explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have computed, for $q = p = 5$ the zeta function of $\bar{C}$. I found that $Z(\bar{C},t) = \frac{1}{1-5t}$.

I realise I have incorrectly phrased my claim for (2). What I instead intended to claim was that $Z(C,t)$ *can be written* as $\frac{f(t)}{(1-t)(1-qt)}$, or more precisely, that $Z(C,t) = \frac{f(t)}{(1-t)(1-qt)} * (1-t)^i$, where $f(t) \in \mathbb{Z}[t]$ and $i \geq 0$. The suggested example works under this claim. Can you tell me if this is true? Is there anywhere I can find a reference for this?